# What is the easiest way to run power shell script on Azure as timer triggered scheduled task?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

What is the simple and clean way to run power shell script in AZURE ?

I am running this as azure function now (powershell), but not sure is this the only way?

Can we use logic app or any other simple way to run power shell script?

Comment: You have the Azure Functions Timer Trigger in [PowerShell Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-powershell) also. Have you checked it!

Comment: Yes, currently running it as an azure function, Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Logic apps cannot run PowerShell directly however you can use [azure automation runbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types?tabs=lps51%2Cpy27).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity

The cost model for [automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/automation/#pricing) is different to Azure logic apps so depending on your job may be better suited.